# How to edit my config file to create two log files while ingesting syslog events?

Tags: rhel, configuration, syslog, rsyslog

I am sending mail message logs and amp logs from the same server 10.10.10.10 via syslog to my RHEL7 server.  I am running rsyslog and have the following config file:

**mail_logs.conf**

```
$template NetworkLog, "/var/log/mail_logs/mail_logs.log"
:fromhost-ip, isequal, "10.10.10.10" -?NetworkLog
& ~
```

And my **mail_logs.log** looks like:

```
Oct 16 10:58:01 server.com mail_mess_logs: Info: Begin Logfile
Oct 16 10:58:01 server.com mail_mess_logs: Info: Version: 0.0.0 SN:...
Oct 16 10:58:01 server.com mail_mess_logs: Info: Time offset from UTC: -14400 seconds
Oct 16 10:58:02 server.com amp_logs: Info: Begin Logfile
Oct 16 10:58:02 server.com amp_logs: Info: Version: 0.0.0 SN:...
Oct 16 10:58:02 server.com amp_logs: Info: Time offset from UTC: -14400 seconds
```

I would like to break these up by `mail_mess_logs` and `amp_logs` so I would have 2 files like:

**mail_mess_logs.log**

```
Oct 16 10:58:01 server.com mail_mess_logs: Info: Begin Logfile
Oct 16 10:58:01 server.com mail_mess_logs: Info: Version: 0.0.0 SN:...
Oct 16 10:58:01 server.com mail_mess_logs: Info: Time offset from UTC: -14400 seconds
```

**amp_logs.log**

```
Oct 16 10:58:02 server.com amp_logs: Info: Begin Logfile
Oct 16 10:58:02 server.com amp_logs: Info: Version: 0.0.0 SN:...
Oct 16 10:58:02 server.com amp_logs: Info: Time offset from UTC: -14400 seconds
```

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using one of the older, more basic *filter* styles supported by rsyslog. A slightly less old style allows you to use expressions including the   `and` operator. The *property* `programname` should hold the `"mail_mess_logs"` string. So you can do

```
if $fromhost-ip=="10.10.10.10" and $programname=="mail_mess_logs" then -/var/log/mail_logs/mail_mess_logs.log
if $fromhost-ip=="10.10.10.10" and $programname=="amp_logs" then -/var/log/mail_logs/amp_logs.log
```

Alternatively, there is a more sophisticated style called [RainerScript](https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/master/rainerscript/index.html).

Comment: Very clean I like it.  @meuh